# Coldfusion seems to get caught up loading UDF's

Tags: coldfusion, user-defined-functions

I am currently running too many sites on a server and I don't think the template cache can handle it.  But, what really seems to be the biggest drag is when I load my UDF library per site.  I say this because whenever I run Fusion Reactor to see where the holdup is, the stacktrace is always sitting on the template that loads the UDF's.

Is the only cure for this more RAM and a higher template cache, or is there a better way?

Maybe I am wrong as well, could there be another issue?

Comment: Please tell about your server configuration and number of sites you have (assumption "too many" is too uncertain).

Comment: About 55 sites, and 44,486 templates (lets just assume that over 60% of that is waste and old sites that are not included in the total sites)  Each site itself has about 500 templates in it.  The server is P4 3Ghz, 2gb RAM, 2048 template cache, 1024mb Min/Max JVM Heap Size.  I know the server is horribly inadequate, and am in the process of migrating to a much better environment, but like i said, anytime there are issue it always seems to be during the loading of the UDF's, so I wanted to make sure that before I migrated, I could figure out what I am doing first =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before increasing the heap and template cache available, look at a few things.

First, do you actually have more templates in the system than you have template cache?  If not, increasing it certainly won't help.  Even if you do, if they aren't called often, it probably won't help, but that's harder to measure.

Second, examine whether the server is having difficulty actually loading the UDFs, or if the page is having a problem executing a UDF.  Are the functions included on the same template that calls them?

Third, find out why it take so long to load this UDF library.  Is it really that big?  Can it be split into smaller libraries?  Is there one (or more) particular UDF that seems to hang the compile process?

Finally, if there is a large UDF library that must be loaded for each request, I would look at using the Application scope to store it.  Include the librar onApplicationStart(), then reference functions as application.myFunction().  This prevents CF from needing to load (and possibly compile) the file at each request.

Comment: Yeah, there are way too many templates on the server. Not all of them get hit often, but from my understanding/stacktraces, every time the requests are hanging it is during a file write operation while hitting the template that loads the udf files. There are about 8 files that comprise the library, so not that many (but there are like 20+ sites). I was mainly speculating that coldfusion has to do extra lifting whilst compiling templates that contain UDFs. The UDFs are all front loaded. Moving them to the application doesn't sound like it would change anything about the template caching though.

Comment: Actually, moving them to the app scope means that they get loaded once at application initialization, which means the templates can then be dumped from the template cache, since they are never recompiled and loaded.  They only get reloaded when the app restarts.  However, you said it dies on a file write -- could it be a drive failure?  Or low disk space?  Or needs a defrag?

Comment: 10/70 GB free, 42% fragmentation, 84% file fragmentation.  Wow, that is horrible.  It's been a while since I've worried about fragmentation.  This may just be it.

Comment: By the way, I've got a defrag scheduled for tonight, so hopefully tomorrow I will be able to let you know if this was the case.

Comment: Well the defrag kinda worked, but I don't know if it helped.  The defrag didn't get all the fragmentation, but it is certainly less.  I will have to keep an eye on the server.  I also applied this http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/865/cpsid_86589.html to see if it helps.

Comment: On systems with a lot of file writes, causing a lot of fragmentation, I've used Diskeeper (http://www.diskeeper.com/diskeeper/server/performance.aspx).  It runs in the background, and seemed to work very well.  It also defragged more files than the built-in tools.